# Getting "Multiple attempts to set the state of this Result" using goog.labs.async.combine

Tags: google-closure-library

Tried using the new goog.labs.async.combine but it's throwing an exception "Multiple attempst to set the state of this Result".  I read the source code and the example and follow it.  Below is portion where I am using combine.  I need the result of the 2 xhr calls before proceeding (example to keep it simple but really I need 3 or 4 more calls). Any help or info I greatly appreciate it.  Jun Victorio

```
var xhr = goog.labs.net.xhr;
var emailUrl = "some url...";
var companyUrl = "some url...";

var emailResults = null;
var companyResults = null;

try {
    emailResults = xhr.getJson(emailUrl, {"headers":{"Accept":"*/*", "Content-     Type":"application/json"}});
    companyResults = xhr.getJson(companyUrl, {"headers":{"Accept":"*/*", "Content-Type":"application/json"}});

    var combineResult = goog.labs.async.combine(emailResults, companyResults);

    goog.labs.async.wait.onSuccess(combineResult, function(results) {
        log("Combined Finished");
    });

    goog.labs.async.wait.onError(combineResult, function(results) {
        log("Combined Finished");
    });

} catch (error) {
   log(error);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's look like Closure Library issue. I had a same problem and this fix works.
http://code.google.com/p/closure-library/issues/detail?id=495